# How to debug this condition of "eth2: tx hang 1 detected on queue 11, resetting adapter"?

Tags: debugging, networking, kernel, nic

I want to send sk_buff by "dev_queue_xmit", when I just send 2 packets, the network card may be hang.

I want to know how to debug this condition.

the /var/log/messages is:

```
[root@10g-host2 test]# tail -f /var/log/messages
Sep 29 10:38:22 10g-host2 acpid: waiting for events: event logging is off
Sep 29 10:38:23 10g-host2 acpid: client connected from 2018[68:68]
Sep 29 10:38:23 10g-host2 acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Sep 29 10:38:24 10g-host2 automount[2210]: lookup_read_master: lookup(nisplus): couldn't locate nis+ table auto.master
Sep 29 10:38:24 10g-host2 mcelog: failed to prefill DIMM database from DMI data
Sep 29 10:38:24 10g-host2 xinetd[2246]: xinetd Version 2.3.14 started with libwrap loadavg labeled-networking options compiled in.
Sep 29 10:38:24 10g-host2 xinetd[2246]: Started working: 0 available services
Sep 29 10:38:25 10g-host2 abrtd: Init complete, entering main loop
Sep 29 10:39:41 10g-host2 kernel: vmalloc mmap_buf=ffffc90016e29000  mmap_size=4096
Sep 29 10:39:41 10g-host2 kernel: insmod module wsmmap successfully!
Sep 29 10:39:49 10g-host2 kernel: mmap_buf + 1024 is ffffc90016e29400
Sep 29 10:39:49 10g-host2 kernel: data ffffc90016e2942a, len is 42
Sep 29 10:39:49 10g-host2 kernel: udp data ffffc90016e29422
Sep 29 10:39:49 10g-host2 kernel: ip data ffffc90016e2940e
Sep 29 10:39:49 10g-host2 kernel: eth data ffffc90016e29400
Sep 29 10:39:49 10g-host2 kernel: h_source is ffffc90016e29406, dev_addr is ffff880c235c4750, len is 6result is 0
Sep 29 10:39:50 10g-host2 kernel: mmap_buf + 1024 is ffffc90016e29400
Sep 29 10:39:50 10g-host2 kernel: data ffffc90016e2942a, len is 42
Sep 29 10:39:50 10g-host2 kernel: udp data ffffc90016e29422
Sep 29 10:39:50 10g-host2 kernel: ip data ffffc90016e2940e
Sep 29 10:39:50 10g-host2 kernel: eth data ffffc90016e29400
Sep 29 10:39:50 10g-host2 kernel: h_source is ffffc90016e29406, dev_addr is ffff880c235c4750, len is 6result is 0
Sep 29 10:39:52 10g-host2 kernel: ixgbe 0000:03:00.0: eth2: Detected Tx Unit Hang
Sep 29 10:39:52 10g-host2 kernel:  Tx Queue             <11>
Sep 29 10:39:52 10g-host2 kernel:  TDH, TDT             <0>, <5>
Sep 29 10:39:52 10g-host2 kernel:  next_to_use          <5>
Sep 29 10:39:52 10g-host2 kernel:  next_to_clean        <0>
Sep 29 10:39:52 10g-host2 kernel: ixgbe 0000:03:00.0: eth2: tx_buffer_info[next_to_clean]
Sep 29 10:39:52 10g-host2 kernel:  time_stamp           <fffd3dd8>
Sep 29 10:39:52 10g-host2 kernel:  jiffies              <fffd497f>
Sep 29 10:39:52 10g-host2 kernel: ixgbe 0000:03:00.0: eth2: tx hang 1 detected on queue 11, resetting adapter
Sep 29 10:39:52 10g-host2 kernel: ixgbe 0000:03:00.0: eth2: Reset adapter
Sep 29 10:39:52 10g-host2 kernel: ixgbe 0000:03:00.0: master disable timed out
Sep 29 10:39:53 10g-host2 kernel: ixgbe 0000:03:00.0: eth2: detected SFP+: 5
Sep 29 10:39:54 10g-host2 kernel: ixgbe 0000:03:00.0: eth2: NIC Link is Up 10 Gbps, Flow Control: RX/TX
```

some information of my computer is:

```
ethtool -i eth2
driver: ixgbe
version: 3.21.2
firmware-version: 0x1bab0001
bus-info: 0000:03:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no


LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
Release:    6.5
Codename:   Final
```

kernel version is: 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I use vmalloc() which alloc the memory for skb->data, so this let NIC down. I fix it by use kmalloc().